# Script trigger on email arrive - pipe email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, cron

I have a Codeigniter project, which reads by a Cron every 1 minute an specific inbox email. Based on its subject and body the script do some steps and API procedures.

But I need to decrease the response times (almost immediate), so I have been reading about a script which triggers some code and fire at every email income.

So the use of a CRON its deprecated with the new implementation.

Mi code:

```
//Connect to the imap SERVER
        $imap_user = $this->config->item("imap_user");
        $imap_pass = $this->config->item("imap_password");
        $imap_server = $this->config->item("imap_server");
        $imap_port = $this->config->item("imap_port");

        $driver = new \greeny\MailLibrary\Drivers\ImapDriver($imap_user, $imap_pass, $imap_server, $imap_port, FALSE);
        $connection = new \greeny\MailLibrary\Connection($driver);
        $mailbox = $connection->getMailbox('INBOX');
        $selection = $mailbox->getMails();
        $selection->limit(5);

        echo "<h1>Selection</h1>";

        if (count($selection) > 0) {

            foreach ($selection as $mail) {
            ... //Here is where I do some stuff with email data
            }
```

how do I make a pipe from email arrive at some Controller at Codeigniter?
Thanks!

Comment: depends on the hosting environment and mail server

Comment: Hosting CentOS 6.9 mail server Exim

Comment: add a custom transport: https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_manualroute_router.html with the `command =` calling your script